# Kinesis Firehose - What is S3 extended destination configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

## Question

What is the S3 extended destination configuration and where in the AWS documentation explains clearly what it is for?

As the name suggests, it must be about S3 destination. However, the S3 destination part of the AWS document has no mention.

- [Choose Amazon S3 for Your Destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#create-destination-s3)

If there are articles or blogs which have clear explanation, please provide the pointers.

I have been looking for a clue in the documentations as below, but as often with the AWS documentations, it is not clear. It looks partly related with input record conversion or record processing.

- [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose API Reference - ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration.html)

  > Describes the configuration of a destination in Amazon S3.
- [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose Developer Guide PDF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/firehose-dg.pdf) - Converting Input Record Format (API)

  > If you want Kinesis Data Firehose to convert the format of your input data from JSON
  >   to Parquet or ORC, specify the optional DataFormatConversionConfiguration element in
  >   ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration ...
- [AWS CloudFormation - AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-extendeds3destinationconfiguration.html)

  > The ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration property type configures an Amazon S3 destination for an Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream.
- [Extended S3 Destination](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.html#extended-s3-destination)

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "extended_s3_stream" {
  name        = "terraform-kinesis-firehose-extended-s3-test-stream"
  destination = "extended_s3"

  extended_s3_configuration {
    role_arn   = "${aws_iam_role.firehose_role.arn}"
    bucket_arn = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}"

    processing_configuration {
      enabled = "true"

      processors {
        type = "Lambda"

        parameters {
          parameter_name  = "LambdaArn"
          parameter_value = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda_processor.arn}:$LATEST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Terraform documentation is the best at showing the difference between S3 and Extended S3 destinations: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.html

S3 Extended inherits the S3 destination configuration parameters with extra ones such as `data_format_conversion_configuration` or the `error_output_prefix`

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid the Kinesis Firehose document is so poorly written, I wonder how people can figure out how to use Firehose just from the documentation.

It looks originally the firehose simply relays data to the S3 bucket and there is no built-in transformation mechanism and the S3 destination configuration has no processing configuration as in [AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream S3DestinationConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-s3destinationconfiguration.html).

Then as in [Amazon Kinesis Firehose Data Transformation with AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-kinesis-firehose-data-transformation-with-aws-lambda/), a mechanism to transform records was introduced seemingly around early 2017, so [AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-extendeds3destinationconfiguration.html) has been added.

Apparently people struggle to find the way of how to configure:

- [Does Amazon Kinesis Firehose support Data Transformations programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665829/does-amazon-kinesis-firehose-support-data-transformations-programatically/43701922)

> Well so I figured it out after much effort and documentation scrounging.

Who can figure it out by just reading the AWS document?

- [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose Data Transformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html)

## Firehose extended S3 configurations for lambda transformation

Could not figure out from the AWS document, but it looks the configurations required are below after looking into the actual implementations in the Internet.

[image]

---

## Update

As per the suggestion by Kevin Eid.

- [Resource: aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.html)

> s3_configuration - (Optional) Required for non-S3 destinations. **For S3 destination, use extended_s3_configuration instead**.

```
The extended_s3_configuration object supports the same fields from s3_configuration as well as the following:

    data_format_conversion_configuration - (Optional) Nested argument for the serializer, deserializer, and schema for converting data from the JSON format to the Parquet or ORC format before writing it to Amazon S3. More details given below.
    error_output_prefix - (Optional) Prefix added to failed records before writing them to S3. This prefix appears immediately following the bucket name.
    processing_configuration - (Optional) The data processing configuration. More details are given below.
    s3_backup_mode - (Optional) The Amazon S3 backup mode. Valid values are Disabled and Enabled. Default value is Disabled.
    s3_backup_configuration - (Optional) The configuration for backup in Amazon S3. Required if s3_backup_mode is Enabled. Supports the same fields as s3_configuration object.
```

The s3_configuration is still there due to compatibility or legacy reason only I believe, hence only need to use extended_s3_configuration but the AWS documentation does not explain properly. It is such a pity the AWS documentation does not serve as the source of truth.

Answer (score 1):

First of The ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration property type configures an Amazon S3 destination for an Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream.
See:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-extendeds3destinationconfiguration.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This little screenshot shows new components in `ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration` as compared to `S3DestinationConfiguration`:

[image]

Also, what is and how the extended s3 configuration is defined are shown in API [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/firehose/update-destination.html):

```
{
  "RoleARN": "string",
  "BucketARN": "string",
  "Prefix": "string",
  "ErrorOutputPrefix": "string",
  "BufferingHints": {
    "SizeInMBs": integer,
    "IntervalInSeconds": integer
  },
  "CompressionFormat": "UNCOMPRESSED"|"GZIP"|"ZIP"|"Snappy",
  "EncryptionConfiguration": {
    "NoEncryptionConfig": "NoEncryption",
    "KMSEncryptionConfig": {
      "AWSKMSKeyARN": "string"
    }
  },
  "CloudWatchLoggingOptions": {
    "Enabled": true|false,
    "LogGroupName": "string",
    "LogStreamName": "string"
  },
  "ProcessingConfiguration": {
    "Enabled": true|false,
    "Processors": [
      {
        "Type": "Lambda",
        "Parameters": [
          {
            "ParameterName": "LambdaArn"|"NumberOfRetries"|"RoleArn"|"BufferSizeInMBs"|"BufferIntervalInSeconds",
            "ParameterValue": "string"
          }
          ...
        ]
      }
      ...
    ]
  },
  "S3BackupMode": "Disabled"|"Enabled",
  "S3BackupUpdate": {
    "RoleARN": "string",
    "BucketARN": "string",
    "Prefix": "string",
    "ErrorOutputPrefix": "string",
    "BufferingHints": {
      "SizeInMBs": integer,
      "IntervalInSeconds": integer
    },
    "CompressionFormat": "UNCOMPRESSED"|"GZIP"|"ZIP"|"Snappy",
    "EncryptionConfiguration": {
      "NoEncryptionConfig": "NoEncryption",
      "KMSEncryptionConfig": {
        "AWSKMSKeyARN": "string"
      }
    },
    "CloudWatchLoggingOptions": {
      "Enabled": true|false,
      "LogGroupName": "string",
      "LogStreamName": "string"
    }
  },
  "DataFormatConversionConfiguration": {
    "SchemaConfiguration": {
      "RoleARN": "string",
      "CatalogId": "string",
      "DatabaseName": "string",
      "TableName": "string",
      "Region": "string",
      "VersionId": "string"
    },
    "InputFormatConfiguration": {
      "Deserializer": {
        "OpenXJsonSerDe": {
          "ConvertDotsInJsonKeysToUnderscores": true|false,
          "CaseInsensitive": true|false,
          "ColumnToJsonKeyMappings": {"string": "string"
            ...}
        },
        "HiveJsonSerDe": {
          "TimestampFormats": ["string", ...]
        }
      }
    },
    "OutputFormatConfiguration": {
      "Serializer": {
        "ParquetSerDe": {
          "BlockSizeBytes": integer,
          "PageSizeBytes": integer,
          "Compression": "UNCOMPRESSED"|"GZIP"|"SNAPPY",
          "EnableDictionaryCompression": true|false,
          "MaxPaddingBytes": integer,
          "WriterVersion": "V1"|"V2"
        },
        "OrcSerDe": {
          "StripeSizeBytes": integer,
          "BlockSizeBytes": integer,
          "RowIndexStride": integer,
          "EnablePadding": true|false,
          "PaddingTolerance": double,
          "Compression": "NONE"|"ZLIB"|"SNAPPY",
          "BloomFilterColumns": ["string", ...],
          "BloomFilterFalsePositiveProbability": double,
          "DictionaryKeyThreshold": double,
          "FormatVersion": "V0_11"|"V0_12"
        }
      }
    },
    "Enabled": true|false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. However, who needs to use this and to do what?

Comment: @mon it gives you a lot of options, such as compression, encryption, s3 backup bucket, logging. For example, so you can aggregate all your stream data in compressed format to save on s3 storage cost. You don't have to use all these options, but they are there.